# Hiddenfield is null when accessing from FetchCount() on Objectdatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, subsonic, objectdatasource

I am using subsonic and a gridview with objectdatasource (I have not used an objectdatasource before)

The grid binds just fine, my only problem is that I don't want to keep calling the database to get a count of all the records in the table. So when I call "FetchCount" (the SelectCountMethod) the first time I want to store it ina  hiddenfield (or viewstate). For some reason my hiddenfield is always null when I try and access it, not the value, the actual hidden field. This is also the case if I try storing it in the viewstate.

This is my aspx. Just a gridview, ObjectDatasource and a hiddenfield

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdResults" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
 DataSourceID="PropertiesDataSource" PageSize="10" >
 <Columns >
 <asp:BoundField DataField="PropertyName" />
 </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="PropertiesDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="FetchPagedData" 
TypeName="TestWebsite.Usercontrols.Search.SearchResults" SelectCountMethod="FetchCount" 
StartRowIndexParameterName="start" 
MaximumRowsParameterName="pageLength" EnablePaging="True" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTotalRecords" runat="server" />
```

TypeName="TestWebsite.Usercontrols.Search.SearchResults"  is the namespace of the webpage that the above controls are on.

```
 public int? TotalRecords
    {
        get
        {
            if (hdnTotalRecords.Value != string.Empty) return int.Parse(hdnTotalRecords.Value);
            else return null;
        }
        set { hdnTotalRecords.Value = value.ToString(); }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
             grdResults.DataBind();

    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public PropertyXCollection FetchPagedData(int start, int pageLength)
    { 
        int startIndex;
        if (start == 0)
            startIndex = 1;
        else           
            startIndex = start / pageLength + 1;

        PropertyXCollection collection = GetProperties(startIndex, 10);
        return collection;
    }

    public int FetchCount()
    {
        int returnVal = 0;
        if (TotalRecords != null)
            returnVal = (int)TotalRecords;
        else
        {
            TotalRecords = GetProperties(null, null).Count;
            returnVal = (int)TotalRecords;
        }
        return (int)returnVal;
    }

    PropertyXCollection GetProperties(int? pageIndex, int? pageCount)
    {
        //method that uses subsonic to return a collection of Properties from the database //and passes in the page index and count
    }
```

.

What am I doing wrong?

**MY SOLUTION**

I used the session instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're trying to use `SearchResults` as both a `Page` and the underlying class backing up the `ObjectDataSource`.

As explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.typename.aspx), since your data object methods are not `static`, the `ObjectDataSource` will create a *new* instance of the `SearchResults` class and call the methods on that instance. This means the hidden field will always be `null` and the view state contents will be meaningless.

You can persist the record count in the ASP.NET session state instead, which you can access from the current HTTP context:

```
public int? TotalRecords
{
    get {
        return (int?) HttpContext.Current.Session["TotalRecords"];
    }
    set {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["TotalRecords"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about doing this where I did have access to the  hiddenfield? I tried setting the type as the PropertyXCollection but I kept getting errors. I could not find any examples of how t do that with subsonic. Even if I could would it work?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your comment, but you won't be able to reliably access a `HiddenField` from the underlying class of an `ObjectDataSource`, unless of course you pass it the current `Page` by adding it to its `SelectParameters` collection, and that looks a little overkill IMHO...

Comment: OK, I understand. So my only option really is to either keep calling the database to get the record count or store it in the session? Or somehow make my functions static? Where I wouldn't be able to access either the viewstate or hiddenfield?

Comment: Indeed, if you want the record count to be persisted across postbacks, I don't know of any other way.